# Why does 'diffuse_color' expect four values and not three with Python in 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting, materials

I am attempting to create a plane and set the color; the following code throws an error at this line:

```
bpy.data.materials['RSgreen'].diffuse_color=(0,0,0)
```

the error is:  ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: sequences of dimension 0 should contain 4 items, not 3

which makes no sense to me; diffuse_color calls for 3 parameters in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Material.html?highlight=diffuse_color).

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=4,enter_editmode=False,location=(-2,-2,0.01))
bpy.context.active_object.name='Plane2'
bpy.ops.material.new()
bpy.data.materials[1].name='RSgreen'
bpy.data.materials['RSgreen'].diffuse_color=(0,0,0)
bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(bpy.data.materials['RSgreen'])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You saw the wrong version of document, 2.80 change a lot. Ones should always use new document page for 2.80 version:

[Material(ID) - Blender 2.80 API (latest)](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Material.html?highlight=diffuse_color#bpy.types.Material.diffuse_color)

> ## diffuse_color
>
> Diffuse color of the material
>
> **Type:**
> float array of 4 items in `[0, inf]`, default `(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8)`
>
> <sup>last update: 2020-08-04 Blender 2.91 Alpha</sup>

The four values are represented as: `[Red, Green, Blue, Alpha]` by default rendering pipeline. These values may stay from 0.0 to 1.0 if the color is interpreted as diffuse. Other wise, it doesn't need to less than 1. eg. a light color node might contain a value more than 1 unit.

Comment: What do the parameters mean?  R,G,B,? ??

Comment: @vndep RGB and Alpha

Comment: I am trying to get a green color (RGB=0,113,57; hex=#007139). When I pass the array (0,113,57,1) to .diffuse_color I get a light blue color instead. Same result when I convert the 0-255 values to percentiles. Any suggestions as to how to get that green?   Maybe diffusion_color isn't the right property?

Comment: @vndep The description say it is an float number, and you should always consider the color value is in `0 to 1` rather `0 to 255`. Divide your color value by `255` to fix it

Comment: Thanks! That solves it.