# What does the fourth parameter that 'diffuse_color' takes in Blender 2.9 do?

Tags: python, scripting, materials

It seems that the `diffuse_color` definition has changed in Blender at some point as older scripts in which it was defined by the struct with 3 parameters now it requires the struct with 4.

Does anyone know what is the meaning of the fourth parameter?

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate, won't mark to avoid @RayMairlot)  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145200/cant-set-color-for-a-material-in-blender-python-2-8

Comment: @batFINGER They're very close, just unfortunate that the parameters are only explicitly explained in the comments. Could just add a note to the accepted answer that the new value is alpha (if that's what it is) and close as duplicate.

Comment: @RayMairlot   Good one, sorted.  Suggest this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189765/object-operators-causing-crash is your classic XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diffuse_color take 4 parameters as RGBA

red, green, blue, alpha

mat.diffuse_color = (red_v, grn_v, blu_v, alpha_v)  # viewport color